# Is there a way to categorize firestore documents into two then display them in two different tables?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create an appointments section with upcoming and past button where each button (when clicked) displays a table based on defined condition. They also both use the same collection. However, whenever I clicked one of them, it looks like they are just looping.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import db from './firebase';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const App = () => {
  // get current date
  var currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState([]);

  const handleUpcoming = async () => {
    const response = db.collection('accounts').where('schedule', '>', currentDate);;
    const data = await response.get();
    const newAccounts = data.docs.map(item => item.data())
    setAccounts(newAccounts);
  }

  const handlePast = async () => {
    const response = db.collection('accounts').where('schedule', '<', currentDate);;
    const data = await response.get();
    const newAccounts = data.docs.map(item => item.data())
    setAccounts(newAccounts);
  }

  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <h1>Appointments</h1>
      <div className="button-container">
        <button onClick={handleUpcoming()}>Upcoming</button>
        <button onClick={handlePast()}>Past</button>
        <div className = "scrollbar">
        <table>
          {
            accounts && accounts.map(account=>{
              return(
              <tr>
                <td className="appointmentDataOne">{account.name}
                <div className="appointmentDataTwo">{account.email}</div></td>
                <td className="appointmentDataOne">{account.schedule}</td>
                <td className="appointmentDataTwo">{account.service}</td>
                <td className="appointmentDataTwo">{account.mobileNumber}</td>
              </tr>
              )
            })
        }
        </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```